# Next.js link not routing from the same page with different parameters

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

When trying to go from route `/category/X` to `/category/Y` it changes the address on the url bar but the page does not rerender with the new data.
When refreshing the page it loads fine.
When routing from a different page it works fine.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const { data: categories } = await axios.get(`API ENDPOINT`);
    const paths = categories.map(category => ({
      params: { id: category },
    }));

    return { paths, fallback: true }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const id = context.params.id;
    let preloadedProducts = await axios.get(`API ENDPOINT`);
    
    return {
        props: {
            preloadedProducts
        },
        revalidate: 10
    }
}
```

And the way I link to this pages is:

```
<Link href={`/category/${categoryId}/`} passHref={true}>
    {link.title}</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: Can you show the hole component?

Comment: @yousoumar
<div className="header-submenu-categories">
            { subMenu.map((item) => (
                <Link href={`/category/${categoryId}/`} passHref={true}>
                    {link.title}</a>
                </Link>
             )) }
</div>

Comment: I mean the component that's consuming `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @yousoumar
https://pastebin.pl/view/58887866
This is the category page. It works fine when manually refreshing but not when trying to access it from the same page

Comment: @yousoumar do you think it's a problem with react-infinite-scroll-component being prerendered?

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

So I just encountered this issue and router.push() is a promise, you just have to hook into it or await it and then you can do a router.reload();

```
router.push(`/sameroute?param=${param}`).then(() =>{
  router.reload();
});
```

I'm on next: 12.3.1

hope this helps!